# How to extract the text data between nodes from an XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="home.css"?>
<Header type="text">
  <encodingDesc>
    <samplingDesc>Samples taken from page 10-11,20-21,38-39, 54-55, 70-71, 80-81, 98-99, 122-123, 142-143, 148-149, 162-163, 174-175 </samplingDesc>
  </encodingDesc>
  <sourceDesc>
    <mainContent>
      <source> Abhinesh
        <category>Natural, Physical and Professional Sciences</category>
        <subcategory>Textile Technology</subcategory>
        <text> Book </text>
        <title> cloths </title>
        <vol> 1 </vol>
        <issue/>
      </source>
      <textDes>
        <type/>
        <headline/>
        <author> V. Nurjan </author>
        <translator/>
        <words>3364</words>
      </textDes>
    </mainContent>
  </sourceDesc>
  <profileDesc>
    <creation>
      <date> 21-Dec-2010 </date>
      <inputter> Abhinesh </inputter>
    </creation>
    <langUsage> Telugu </langUsage>
    <textClass>
      <channel mode="w"> print </channel>
      <domain type="public"/>
    </textClass>
  </profileDesc>
</Header>
```

I checked every example on the internet but they are only giving the code for simple XML files but not this type. How can I extract the tagged data from such an XML file?

Comment: What language?  Also, you appear to have a typo next to `<Source>` under `<MainContent>` - you have text after the Source element.  If it's not a typo, than you do not have valid XML.

Comment: @Tim I am quite sure this XML is pretty valid. I think text can be located like this. In fact I have already checked it and the Internet Explorer shows it without giving parsing errors.

Comment: @Jagger - `<mainContent><source> Abhinesh <category>Natural, Physical and Professional Sciences</category>` is **NOT** valid.  The text "Abhinesh" is between the `<source>` element and the `<category>` child element.  That is not legal.

Comment: @Tim As I said it can be open without any problems in IE, I will check what Saxon does with this XML file.

Comment: @Jagger - OP edited the post and removed the text, so it appears it was a typo.

Comment: @Tim It was not a typo. And it was a valid xml. Saxon does not complain about it. Even if you see in your everyday life xml files only with elements without surrounding texts, it does not mean that those texts are not allowed.

Comment: @Abhinesh You needn't have changed the xml. It is pretty valid.

Comment: yep... i changed it...i want content of all child nodes that are in <sourcDec> tag. to make it multi loop i just added one more tag that is <mainContent>...my aim is to extract the data in inner tags thats why i changed the xml file a little... of course its not the real file.

Comment: @Abhinesh Have you ever heard about XSL transformations? A one would suit you well in this case.

Comment: No not yet...I am searching for a better option to get tagged data and i encountered Dom parser only...now i will check that.

Comment: @Jagger - I stand corrected.  I could have sworn you couldn't do that, but I did some research and you can.  Apologies.

Comment: @Tim No problem. I could agree to the fact that it looks pretty strange. However the XML spec allows it.

Comment: @Tim yep...No problem.thanks for your comments.i am a rookie in this parsing...so please don't thinks he is asking a stupid questions...thank u.

Comment: @Tim I have got an epiphany just now. The good example of text between parent and child elements are the white spaces when you have your xml file formatted.

Comment: @Abhinesh I think using XSL transformation is probably more pragmatic in your case. Writing something that uses DOM or SAX parser might be a waste of time, unless you want to learn how to parse an xml file programmatically by yourself.

Comment: @Jagger an even better example is XHTML - `<p>Paragraph with some <strong>important</strong> information.</p>`

Comment: @Jagger thanks for your suggestion.i will look more on it, to get grip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple XSL Transformation for your purpose. To extract all the texts as a text file you could make use of the following XSL stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:if test="boolean(normalize-space(text()))">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())" /><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To execute this stylesheet you would need an XSL Parser like [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) or [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) if you use Unix like operating system.

You could also test it easily with IE, Firefox or any other browser you want.

Just save the stylesheet in the same folder your xml source file is. As for example `test.xsl` and then change the header of your xml file from

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="home.css"?>
```

to

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
```

Then the output will look like that

```
Samples taken from page 10-11,20-21,38-39, 54-55, 70-71, 80-81, 98-99, 122-123, 142-143, 148-149, 162-163, 174-175
Abhinesh
Natural, Physical and Professional Sciences
Textile Technology
Book
cloths
1
V. Nurjan
3364
21-Dec-2010
Abhinesh
Telugu
print
```